# HDMI works only in safe mode

Tags: hdmi

I've a Samsung LCD 32" (UE32) and I've tried to connect it via HDMI to my Raspberry Pi2 with Raspbian.
Nothing works, the only configuration where I can see the monitor is with hdmi_safe=1 at the cool resolution of 592x448px.
So I've tried to check my monitor configuration.

Using:

```
 /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
```

I've received:

```
Group CEA has 14 modes:
           mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 5: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
  (native) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
           mode 17: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 18: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
  (prefer) mode 19: 1280x720 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 20: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
           mode 31: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
           mode 32: 1920x1080 @ 24Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 33: 1920x1080 @ 25Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 34: 1920x1080 @ 30Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
```

While using:

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
```

This is the result:

```
Group DMT has 19 modes:
           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
           mode 5: 640x480 @ 72Hz 4:3, clock:31MHz progressive
           mode 6: 640x480 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:31MHz progressive
           mode 8: 800x600 @ 56Hz 4:3, clock:36MHz progressive
           mode 9: 800x600 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:40MHz progressive
           mode 10: 800x600 @ 72Hz 4:3, clock:50MHz progressive
           mode 11: 800x600 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:49MHz progressive
           mode 16: 1024x768 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:65MHz progressive
           mode 17: 1024x768 @ 70Hz 4:3, clock:75MHz progressive
           mode 18: 1024x768 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:78MHz progressive
           mode 21: 1152x864 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:108MHz progressive
           mode 28: 1280x800 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:83MHz progressive
           mode 32: 1280x960 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:108MHz progressive
           mode 35: 1280x1024 @ 60Hz 5:4, clock:108MHz progressive
           mode 36: 1280x1024 @ 75Hz 5:4, clock:135MHz progressive
           mode 47: 1440x900 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:106MHz progressive
           mode 48: 1440x900 @ 75Hz 16:10, clock:136MHz progressive
           mode 51: 1600x1200 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:162MHz progressive
           mode 58: 1680x1050 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:146MHz progressive
```

So I've tried to edit my /boot/config.txt file using CEA configuration:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

plus with/without the following lines:

```
hdmi_force_edid_audio=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
```

But nothing has chaged. Without safe mode I can't see anything.
Any idea?

Comment: I've found only another configuration which works but always at low resolution (hdmi_group=2,hdmi_mode=16).

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in the cable!
I've replaced the cable with the one of my other (newer) TV and it works fine!
Configuration is:

My final configuration is:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

Hope it helps!